# Can't use System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost in .NET Standard2

Tags: .net-standard-2.0

I would like to use the in .NET Standard2.0 but I can't use the ServiceHost under System.ServiceModel. Is there a workaround to use ServiceHost in .NET standard2?

Any inputs are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is preventing you from using it? Are you getting an error? What is the error message? And when are you getting it?

Comment: it is not possible, as [not available](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost) for .net standard.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks on that one. Do you know when will they add it? Or is there a workaround that we could do to achieve the WCF on .NET Standard2.0?[EDIT]Wait I believed you misunderstood my question. It's .NET Standard 2.0 not .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: @NightOwl888 It will throw a compile error "not found" even though I add System.ServiceModel in reference.

Comment: I understand your issue. And it is not part of .net standard 2.0 so you can't use it. WCF is .net framework only. Why do you want to use it?